# Bootstrap: select/option list doesn't get refreshed after programmatically adding item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following select/option

```
<select class="bs-select form-control">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

In my script section, I have this, which works fine. The styles are being applied

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bs-select').selectpicker();
});
```

I have a button that does this:

```
$('.bs-select').append($('<option>', {
                        value: 0,
                        text: "test"
                    }));
```

However my select list isn't refreshed.

I tried adding

```
$('.bs-select').selectpicker();
```

after the append but it still doesn't work.

My select list gets refreshed if I remove the `$('.bs-select').selectpicker()` in `$(document).ready`

How can I get my list to refresh after adding an item?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `refresh` after adding new option

```
$('.bs-select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: There's a 10 min wait-out period before I can accept an answer. I'm sure you know that.

Comment: Datatables fnInitComplete and ajax dataFilter work with refresh